# ASP.NET 4.5 Setting SMTP Encoding in Config

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, smtp

I am working on a website I didn't write so I don't know it inside out. The default setting for SMTP mail encoding is being set to ASCII (somewhere) but I want it to be UTF-8. It seems this should be in a config file but I can't find where it is specified. I'm aware that I can manually set it in the code but I want the change to be site wide. The emails are in html. Everywhere else on the site except for email seem to be correctly set to UTF-8.

Currently, my email headers have this setting for encoding:

```
    Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
```

And it should be:

```
    Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

or something to that effect.

Here is some sample code that is used. I don't think it is that informative. The email values are being produced in another class. This is the part that sends the email.

```
        using System.Net.Mail;
        ....
        MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
        msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
        msg.From = new MailAddress(shopEmail, (Globals.Settings.Shop.MailName));
        // This just pulls these values from another class
        msg.Subject = editEmailTemplates.EmailSubject;
        msg.Body = editEmailTemplates.EmailBody;
        SmtpClient mailClient = new SmtpClient();
        try
        {
            mailClient.Send(msg);
        }
        catch(SmtpException)
        {
        }
```

Comment: where's the code used for generating the email?

Comment: You should really let us know what you are using to send the emails and supply a short snippet of code if possible.

Comment: @Steve - does this code help?

Comment: Setting encoding via Microsoft Documentation : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.bodyencoding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @GenericJam You will see from the page that the default is us-ascii.

Comment: @Steve - Been there. They are setting the values manually in the code. I am looking to set it to the default value for the whole site.

Comment: @Steve - So the default for the site settings is UTF-8 but for emails, it's us-ascii. That's a bit inconsistent. Thanks for the info. Maybe there is no way to set it for the whole site.

Comment: @GenericJam I don't think this is possible to do as a Mail setting in the Web.Config. However using <appSettings> and <add key="x">, you could set it there and have it wrapped up in a custom emailer class to take appropriate action on whatever it is set to.